# How to retrieve topic title while in flow

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using XMetal's default stylesheet to generate PDF. My source xml file has a "title" tag that I want to keep track of, previously ,I used the following code:

```
<fo:inline>
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="current-header"/>
</fo:inline>
```

However, this will never work since Markers can only be retrieved in static content in FO, not in the main
fo:flow. So my question is, if I am in the main fo:flow, how could I retrieve the title of the xml file?

Comment: Can't you just use something like `<xsl:value-of select='/path/to/document/title'/>` in the stylesheet that generates the FO markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your data looks like this:

```
<title name="Section 1">
    <tag1>
        <tag2>
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
</title>
```

and your template is currently in `tag2`.

Then you just use select by `ancestor` axis:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::title/@name"/>
```

If your `title`s are nested, just use `ancestor::title[1]/@name`